# Geolocation very slow in OL3

Tags: geolocation, openlayers-3

I'm trying to use the geolocation with Openlayers 3, but find it very slow.
I've tried this example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/examples/geolocation.html
but even on this example page it is very slow.

Any idea if there is a way to improve the speed?

Thanks!

Comment: By slow, do you mean that it's slow to retrieve the position or slow to load the map? Could you describe the expected vs real behavior?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. It's slow to find the position and to show it on the map. And when I say slow, I counted 40 s between checking the box to start tracking and the point appearing on the map. Is that normal?

Comment: What device and browser did you use?

Comment: wow, I was not expecting this! I use safari on mac.. on chrome/windows it took barely a couple of seconds; on chrome/mac, something like 5s. Is there a reason for that?